# Java Array Reverse logic

Tags: arrays, loops, reverse

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arr[] = new int[5];
        System.out.println("Enter the values in the array");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int temp;
            int j = 4;
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            j--;
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

This logic is not reversing the array of integers why?????

> input 123
>
> output is 0123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach you may try here is to simply swap each element in the array across the middle position:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
for (int i=0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    int j = arr.length - i - 1;
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

This prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The problem with your current logic is largely this line:

```
int j = 4;
```

You assign the upper pointer to the array as `4`, for *each* iteration of the loop.  Instead, the value `j` should be initialized as `4` outside of the loop, and then decremented during each iteration.  But, I would probably use the version I gave above.

Comment: @Aaditya I have given an explanation of a few things which your current code is doing incorrectly.

Comment: i removed the variable j and temp from loop now the output is    input: 1234     output: 12340

Comment: Unless you stop midway, you will end up swapping the items all over again ending up with the same string you started with

Comment: @Aaditya What do you think the loop condition `i < arr.length/2` is doing? `:-)`

Comment: now it is working correctly except the output include 0 before printing the output

Comment: @Aaditya is the problem still persisting? You need i < arr.length - 1 in the for where you read the values. Since the very last value is not loaded, it's initialized by 0.

Comment: @Aaditya sorry, I mean i < arr.length

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your code:

1. You need to initialize `j` *before* the array. If you initialize it to 4 inside the array, then you will always swap the last element with the `i`'th element and then decrease `j`.
2. With `i` stop at `arr.length / 2`. Imagine this scenario:

You have the following set: 1 2 3 4 5

If you go to the end, then these will be the states:

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 5 2 3 4 1
>
> 5 4 3 2 1
>
> 5 4 3 2 1
>
> 1 4 3 2 5
>
> 1 2 3 4 5

because you swap correctly the values until you reach half of the data set and then you swap it back. You will need to stop at half way.

Comment: Nice answer +1, and you correctly pointed out the necessary reason for only iterating half the array.  I did it because of efficiency, but that's not the real reason.

Answer (score 0):

As the last element is not saved it is set to 0. So the array that is saved is 12340 not 1234

The reversing logic is incorrect as you are always swapping with the last element.

```
1st iteration - 1 swaps with 0 - New string -> 02341
2nd iteration - 2 swaps with 1 - New string -> 01342
3rd iteration - 3 swaps with 2 - New string -> 01243
4th iteration - 4 swaps with 3 - New string -> 01234
```

If you print out the whole string each time it'll make sense.
As you are printing only the swapped character in each iteration it is unclear what is happening

Comment: i removed the variable j and temp from the loop now input is 1234 and output is 12340

Comment: thats because the loop is being run till the end. If you swap twice you'll end up with the same output !